# How to host applications on separate paths of a subdomain?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two application "foo" and "bar" running on ports 4560 and 4570 respectively.

Both of them have paths that look like `/api/v1/hello` and `/api/v1/world`.

I'm trying to access them in the following manner:

- https://src.saurabh.sm/foo
- https://src.saurabh.sm/bar

For which I have the below NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    server_name src.saurabh.sm www.src.saurabh.sm;

    proxy_set_header      Connection "";                 
    proxy_http_version    1.1;                           
    proxy_set_header      Host                            $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP                       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For                 $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto               $scheme;
    add_header            Access-Control-Allow-Methods    'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

    location /foo/ {
        rewrite ^/foo/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4560/;
    }

    location /bar/ {
        rewrite ^/bar/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4570/;
    }
}
```

The homepage of the applications (`http://localhost:4560/foo/` and `http://localhost:4570/bar/`) work fine, but clicking any link on the webpages returs a 404 because the links dont have `foo` and `bar` in them.

From the terminal, I can access them like:

- `curl http://localhost:4560/foo/api/v1/hello`
- `curl http://localhost:4560/foo/api/v1/world`
- `curl http://localhost:4570/bar/api/v1/hello`
- `curl http://localhost:4570/bar/api/v1/world`

How can I ensure that `foo` and `bar` come before all endpoints in the browser?

Comment: welcome, please read carefully [ask]. moreover are the logs of the Webservers a secret, or a other reason why it is not shown?

Comment: I dont thinks logs are needed here. 404 indicates not found and I've indicated what works and what doesn't as part of my question. I'm looking to prepend text before all application paths.

Comment: the log are essentially and nessescary, due it shows which path are really used. moreover it is a requirement for this business environment. if there is no business relationship, you may have to ask on superuser.com

Comment: You state that `http://localhost:4560/foo/` works fine, but your Nginx locations are actually sending `http://localhost:4560/` - you see the `rewrite ^/foo/?(.*)$ /$1 break;` - that removes `/foo` before `localhost:4560` sees it.

Comment: Hi Richard - I'm looking to serve application `foo` on `localhost:4560/foo/`. The application endpoints look like `/api/v1/hello` and `localhost:4560/foo/api/v1/hello` works. If I remove the `rewrite` directive, I'm getting the same result. Is there a way I can ensure that `foo` is preserved without making application level changes?